# Creating a simple 4 function calculator. Using visual studios 2017

Tags: c++

I know this is not the place to ask for help on HW but it's due tonight and I think I did a good 80% of the lab.

Write a program, which will act as a simple four-function calculator. That is it will read a number,  read an operator,  read another number,  then do the operation.  The calculator works with integers and uses four functions:  +, -,  *,  and  /.  After the first operation is completed, the program will read another operator and uses the result of the previous operation as the first value for the next operation.  If the user enters a C  the result is cleared and then the user starts entering a new number.  If the user enters an X,  the calculator is turned off.  The various input values  (i.e.  numbers,  operators,  commands) will be followed by the ENTER key. Your program should prompt the user on what the user is to do. The commands C and X may be entered in place of an operator.

The part where I check if the number is a number was given to us by the professor and he just said to copy and use it without explaining much.

My errors are:
1. When I press 'c' after entering the first number I don't know how I can make it restart. 
2. After pressing 'c' it just asks me the second number and no matter what I enter it prints the last else statement.
3. Also, I don't know how to place the final answer i get back into Num1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <ctype.h>  


int main()
{
    char    Digit1, Digit2;
    bool    FirstNum, SecondNum;
    bool    NegativeNum1, NegativeNum2;
    int     Num1, Num2;
    char    Op;
    bool    ValidNum1, ValidNum2;
    bool    ValidOp = true;
    bool    clear = false;

    clear = true;


        do {
            cout << "Enter the first number " << endl;
            FirstNum = true;
            NegativeNum1 = false;
            Num1 = 0;
            ValidNum1 = true;
            while ((Digit1 = cin.get()) != '\n')
            {
                if ((Digit1 == '-') && FirstNum)
                    NegativeNum1 = true;
                else
                    if (isdigit(Digit1))
                        Num1 = (Num1 * 10) + (Digit1 - '0');
                    else
                        ValidNum1 = false;
                FirstNum = false;
            }
            if (!ValidNum1)
                cout << "Not valid, try again" << endl;
            else;
        } while (!ValidNum1);
        if (NegativeNum1)
            Num1 = -Num1;
        else;
        cout << "Finished with number " << Num1 << endl;

        do {
            cout << "Enter an operator, press 'c' to clear or 'x' to exit. " << endl;
            cin >> Op;
            switch (Op)
            {
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                return 0;
                break;
            case '+':
                clear = false;
                break;
            case '-':
                clear = false;
                break;
            case '*':
                clear = false;
                break;
            case '/':
                clear = false;
                break;
            default:
                ValidOp = false;
                cout << "Not valid, please enter '+', '-', '*', '/', 'c' or 'x' as an operator." << endl;
            }

        } while (!ValidOp);

        cin.ignore();   // skip the enter key that is on the keyboard
        do {
            cout << "Enter the second number " << endl;
            SecondNum = true;
            NegativeNum2 = false;
            Num2 = 0;
            ValidNum2 = true;
            while ((Digit2 = cin.get()) != '\n')
            {
                if ((Digit2 == '-') && SecondNum)
                    NegativeNum2 = true;
                else
                    if (isdigit(Digit2))
                        Num2 = (Num2 * 10) + (Digit2 - '0');
                    else
                        ValidNum2 = false;
                SecondNum = false;
            }
            if (!ValidNum2)
                cout << "Not valid, try again" << endl;
            else;
        } while (!ValidNum2);
        if (NegativeNum2)
            Num2 = -Num2;
        else;
        cout << "Finished with number " << Num2 << endl;

        if (Op == '+')
        {
            cout << Num1 << " + " << Num2 << " = " << Num1 + Num2 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Op == '-')
            {
                cout << Num1 << " - " << Num2 << " = " << Num1 - Num2 << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Op == '*')
                {
                    cout << Num1 << " * " << Num2 << " = " << Num1 * Num2 << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Op == '/' && Num2 != 0)
                    {
                        cout << Num1 << " / " << Num2 << " = " << Num1 / Num2 << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Cannot perform this operation. Denominator cannot be 0" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Never let things get to the point where you have more than one error. Write a bit of code. Test until you're sure it works. Add more functionality and test. Rinse, repeat. Adding bugs onto buggy code doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I find myself thinking this would work better on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Another recommendation: get rid of those empty `else`s Sooner or later someone's going to mess up and they are warning spam, making it harder to spot real problems in the code.

Comment: What empty elses?

Comment: `if (!ValidNum2)
                cout << "Not valid, try again" << endl;
            else;` <- that one, for for example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's only for working code.

Comment: This would be a great time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: On an unrelated but stylistic note (that can also prevent bugs due to slight mistakes), but when you don't have anything to put in the `else` part, you can skip the `else` completely. The `else` is optional.

Comment: Problem number 1 is writing correct behaviour for 'C'. If you back up your code and then remove everything but code to handle 'C', you can work on and solve 'C' in isolation. You may even find better ways to write the rest of the program. For example, if the calculating is done inside a function  with nothing but local variables, you can return from the function when someone presses 'C' and everything is automatically cleaned up and then reset for you when you reenter the function.

Comment: I don't wanna mess with it because my professor wrote that part and he's the only one reading it so i don't think he would get confused.

Comment: I'm gonna try the correct behavior for C thing.

Answer (score 0):

C Program to Create Simple Calculator using Switch Case

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
 char Operator;
 float num1, num2, result = 0;

 printf("\n Please Enter an Operator (+, -, *, /)  :  ");
 scanf("%c", &Operator);

 printf("\n Please Enter the Values for two Operands: num1 and num2  :  ");
 scanf("%f%f", &num1, &num2);

 switch(Operator)
 {
    case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;              
    case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n You have enetered an Invalid Operator ");                                
   }

   printf("\n The result of %.2f %c %.2f  = %.2f", num1, Operator, num2, 
 result);

    return 0;
}
```